# Java instanceof with Object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oop, instanceof

I have a spring boot project with Java 17. I am calling a third party API to get the list of records. If the records are present I do get the 200 OK response with list of records and in case records are not present I do get a 200 OK response with another JSON schema. To verify whether the response if of a type list of records or an error I am using instanceof but it is not working and always go to else condition.

```
HttpEntity<Void> request = new HttpEntity<>(httpHeaders);
    ResponseEntity<Object> response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, request, Object.class);

    if (response.getBody() instanceof ZohoError zohoError) {
      return Collections.emptyList();
    } else {
      return (List<Leave>) response.getBody();
    }
```

---

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class ZohoError {

  private String message;

  @JsonAlias("errorcode")
  private String errorCode;

  @JsonAlias("Response status")
  private int responseStatus;

}
```

Comment: This won't work as it the type you are using is `Object.class` so that is also what you get as a result. Without the actual type Jackson doesn't know what to create.

Comment: Perhaps, you should try `response.getBody() instanceof Map` as a hack (because jackson creates a map for json objects, afaik), and that's different from a `List`, which jackson would create if you received an json array.

Comment: how do you expect it to map to `ZohoError` when you use `restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, request, Object.class)`?

Answer (score 1):

As your third party API returns different schemas with same http code (which smells for me), you can't use RestTemplate to get needed object - you don't know the object type.
You can get RestTemplate response as String, parse it to JsonNode using ObjectMapper (Jackson). Then decide which schema is this by some telling attributes. And parse response string to defined type using ObjectMapper.